# XStream conversion exception: Marshalling rejected

Tags: java, javafx, xstream

I'm getting the following error on serialization:

> com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: Security
>   alert. Marshalling rejected.

My code is below; the error is on the line marked.

```
public class SerializeVisitor implements Visitor {

public static final String ID = "id";
private XStream serializer = new XStream(new DomDriver());
private Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();

/**
 * @see Visitor#visit(Visitee)
 *
 * @param v the object to be visited, must implement the Visitee interface. Normally passed a reference to this,
 */
@Override
public void visit(Visitee v) {
    try {
        Field f = v.getClass().getDeclaredField(DATA_UTIL.getString(ID));
        if(!f.isAccessible()) f.setAccessible(true);
        String id = (String) f.get(v);
        System.out.println(id);
        String serialized = serializer.toXML(v); //ERROR HERE
        data.put(id, serialized);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        DialogFactory.showError(String.format(StartView.getErrorBundle().getString(AuthoringVisitor.XML_SV_ERR), v.getClass().toString()));
    }
}

/**
 * Clear the map and return the old value stored inside it. The map should only ever be one entry long, since this will
 * visit one object at a time before returning to the dispatching object.
 *
 * @return The class name of the serialized object and the serialized representation of that object
 */
@Override
public Map<String, String> getStateFromVisit() {
    return data;
}
}
```

Here is the first section of the stack trace:

```
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream$InternalBlackList.marshal(XStream.java:2550)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:69)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:58)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller$1.convertAnother(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:84)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:274)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.writeField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:250)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.<init>(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:213)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doMarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:144)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:90)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:69)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:58)
```

Any idea what might be causing this? Thank you!

EDIT: more code added above

Comment: what does v look like? Post some more details for v.

Comment: updated above! v is a visitee object that I want to serialize. It has the method:  
    public void accept(Visitor v) {
  v.visit(this);
 }
that takes a visitor

Comment: Post the full stack trace. And how is this related to JavaFX?

Comment: The full stack trace is 1400 lines, and is basically just all repeats. Even above you can see that the last two lines are repeats of the part of the stace trace above them. I tagged javafx because I'm using it for the frontend and I know you can't serialize javafx nodes, so I thought it might be causing the issue.

Comment: I would suggest: (1) Post a [MCVE] since all the reflection part seems to have nothing to do with the error and there's only 1 LOC which is relevant, `serializer.toXML(v)`, and we don't even know the value of `v`. (2) Explain what you are trying to achieve; if you're trying to serialize JavaFX components there are other ways.